# Создать html-элемент, описание которого пришло из props, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент, который принимает проп `elem`, и а сам компонент должен обернуть в него свой вывод или во фрагмент, если проп не пришёл. Подобный механизм есть в Material-UI.

```js
<Show elem="div" />
```

Должно вывывести:

```html
<div>/* Some Stuff Here */</div>
```

а это:

```js
<Show />
```

Вернёт фрагмент:

```html
/* Some Stuff Here */
```

Ещё пример:

```html
<Show elem="ol">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
</Show>
```

Вывод:

```html
<ol>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы хотите из родительского компонента передать пропс для отрисовки чего либо, если он приходит. Вы можете просто воспользоваться проверкой пропса на этапе рендера:

```
const Parent = () => {

  return (
      <Show content="Something text" />
  )
}


const Show = ({content}) => {

  return content ? (<div>{content}</div>) : null
}
```

Альтернативный пример рендера на основе пропса:

```
const Show = (htmlElement) => {

  const renderElement = (ChildComponent) => {
    if (htmlElement === "ol") { // проверяем пришедший пропс
      return <ol><ChildComponent /></ol> // возвращаем собранный компонент (если вариантов тегов будет 3 и больше, рекомендую использовать switch case)
    }
  }

  return (
    renderElement(<li />) // вызываем функцию renderElement и передаем ей дочерний компонент, который хотим положить внутрь пропсового элемента
  )
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не правильно, хотя мне казалось, что я описал всё довольно точно. Добавил ещё один пример в пост.

Comment: @Евгений и что тут неправильного? Я дал вам вариант отрисовки любого компонента на основе пропса. Если вы имеете ввиду отрисовку компонента на этапе рендера родительского компонента, то могу предложить рендер результата функции. Пример добавлю в ответ.

Comment: Второй вариант больше подходит, просто хотелось бы избежать кучи условий.

Comment: @Евгений погуглил, оказывается можно это сделать без особого синтаксиса, просто передаете пропс и вставляете в теги дочернего элемента. <recievedProps></recievedProps>